# cakephp model has 0 or 1 relationship

Tags: mysql, cakephp

In cakephp, I have Company and Profile model.  I would like to establish Company has 0 or 1 Profile relationship.  Is it appropriate to use Company hasOne Profile, and Profile belongsTo Company?  Is there any implication I need to be aware of?  The table's schema is below.  Thanks.

```
create table companies (
  id char(36) NOT NULL,
  type int(10) NOT NULL,
  primary key (id)
);
create table profiles (
  id char(36) NOT NULL,
  company_id char(36) NOT NULL,
  provider_contact varchar(255) NULL,
  primary key (id),
  unique key (company_id),
  foreign key (company_id) references companies(id)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the hasOne/belongsTo Relationship, if a Company has no Profile the sub-array will be empty.

In your profiles table you should use company_id to follow the Cake naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

To follow [CakePHP's conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html), the field needs to be `company_id`, not `companies_id`.

The foreign key constraint is up to you. I typically don't add them. The unique constraint seems incorrect. This would imply that there can only be one profile per company. Which is not the same as a company can have 0 or 1 profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Stick to conventions.

You need to adjust your schema to do that

```
create table companies (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  type int(11) NOT NULL,
  primary key (id)
);

create table profiles (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  company_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  provider_contact varchar(255) NULL,
  primary key (id),
  unique key (company_id),
  foreign key (company_id) references companies(id)
);
```

It is `company_id` as others have mention. And also, ids have to be ints, and autoincremental. It's a pain to have them as chars.